# Google Colab Pro Error: Unrecognized runtime "tensorflow"; defaulting to "python3" Notebook settings

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am running an existing .ipynb which uses TensorFlow and Python3 of course. I am on Colab Pro and set the runtime to "GPU" with High RAM. As soon as I run the notebook I get the error:

Unrecognized runtime "tensorflow"; defaulting to "python3" Notebook settings

What is this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely using a notebook that was not authored in Colab after uploading it to Python.

That notebook requests an environment named "tensorflow", which was likely sensible to the original author. But, that's not the name of any environment in Colab, which selected a Python 3 runtime by default.

You can safely ignore this message. Or, copying or saving the notebook should update the JSON to name the Colab environment used to save it, thereby suppressing the message in the future.